# GCD UITableView asynchronous load images, wrong cells are loaded until new image download

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom cells. I load images asynchronously using Grand Central Dispatch. Everything works fine, but when I scroll down, previously loaded images are shown till the new image is downloaded. Here is my code:

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]])
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,  0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSString *url=[pat stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"comments.txt"];
        NSString *u=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:u];
        NSData *image=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        [image writeToFile:[pat stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"] atomically:YES];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[pat stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]];
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
            NSLog(@"Download");
        });
    });
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"cache");
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[pat stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]];
}
```

Any suggestions appreciated. 
P.S. I reuse the cells

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rather than capturing the cell you need to capture the index path, then get the cell back using:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

That way, if the cell is now off screen you'll get nil back and the image won't be set on the wrong cell.

The other thing you need to add after your `dispatch_async()` is a `cell.imageView.image=somePlaceholderImage`.

E.g.:

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]])
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,  0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSString *url=[pat stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"comments.txt"];
        NSString *u=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:u];
        NSData *image=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        [image writeToFile:[pat stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"] atomically:YES];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[pat stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]];
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
            NSLog(@"Download");
        });
    });
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"cache");
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[pat stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]];
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply... but, could u please provide some example code?

Answer (score 2):

In your `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {` You need to clear out the image, or reset it to your spinner. Since table view rows are reused, this is the behavior you will see.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't UITableViewCell define -(void) prepareForReuse for that purpose?
Override it and clear your imageView in there.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse) you're not supposed to touch the content inside prepareForReuse. You should reset the content in cellForRowAtIndexPath instead.