# Threading issue acts differently on ios 7

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using this [Project](https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGImagePickerController) from github, it is an image picker. <s>I have had to make a very small change since ios7 to make the preview images from your albums show again but with that change now when you leave the picker and come back into it the photos selected (2/5) resets to 0/5 even though I have photos selected. How can I fix this?</s>

The `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)` seems to be taking forever to update the ui even with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` to reload the ui inside of it. When I comment out the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)` the pictures load instantly but other things get broken that depend on the queue.

here is the code snippet with the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)` <s>I changed with the code i changed commented out</s>

AGIPCAssetsController.m:

```
- (void)loadAssets
{
    [self.assets removeAllObjects];

    __ag_weak AGIPCAssetsController *weakSelf = self;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

        __strong AGIPCAssetsController *strongSelf = weakSelf;

        @autoreleasepool {
            [strongSelf.assetsGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

                if (result == nil) 
                {
                    return;
                }

                AGIPCGridItem *gridItem = [[AGIPCGridItem alloc] initWithImagePickerController:strongSelf.imagePickerController asset:result andDelegate:strongSelf];
                if ( strongSelf.imagePickerController.selection != nil && 
                    [strongSelf.imagePickerController.selection containsObject:result])
                {
                    gridItem.selected = YES;
                }
                [strongSelf.assets addObject:gridItem];
            }];
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [strongSelf reloadData];

        });

    });
    [strongSelf reloadData];

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Benoit I want to know how to update the picker to know how many photos are selected. It did this correctly before I removed the dispatch but dispatch needs to be removed for it to work in ios7 correctly

Comment: I tried that class but it doesn't show me any images even when I use your fix. You may want to dig deeper to see what is the root issue here, what you are trying to do is a workaround, not the proper fix.

Comment: @lawicko Yes I have found out I need to keep the `dispatch_async` in there but I just dont understand why pictures show up in ios6 but they take forever to show up in ios7

Comment: @BluGeni so you say they will eventually show up? I'd suggest updating the original question then.

Comment: The `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW` queue is a low-priority queue. The behaviour you're describing sounds like what I'd expect from libdispatch's normal queue scheduling.

Comment: @cbowns how does this describe that it works perfectly in ios6 like this and if I change it to HIGH nothing changes

Comment: I must be misunderstanding what behaviour you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent quite a bit of time with this code and I couldn't find a proper solution. Apparently the issue has come up on github, and a user offered a fix:

https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGImagePickerController/issues/19

But apparently he just removed all the blocks running in background, so I suppose that for a large amount of images the performance would be bad.

My hunch is that inside a dispatch_async block runs code that calls some UIKit function,
 and thus the behaviour is basically undefined.

For example it seems to me that the `setAsset` function in **AGIPGridItem.m** is called inside the dispatch_async you posted. It is calling UImage, and although it's inside a lock, it should be still be executed on the background thread, while all the UIKit code should be executed on the main one.

[UITableViewCell load images and reused cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187172/uitableviewcell-load-images-and-reused-cells)

But even if I wrap the call inside a  `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...)` it doesn't work yet.

It seems that the call `[view removeFromSuperview];` in `setItems` in **AGIPGridell.m** is responsible somehow, but removing it has the side effect of creating a memory leak (unsurprisingly).

Answer (score 6):

`AGIPCGridItem` is subclass of `UIView`. **Don't work with UIKit objects on background thread.**

Make sure you need the background thread and if you do, put only heavy tasks to background. Creating an `UIView` should not be that case.

Also, it's not recommended to use `PRIORITY_LOW` use simple `PRIORITY_DEFAULT`.

**Edit:** If you are curious *why* it did work on iOS 6: That's implementation detail of UIKit. It still was wrong, but somehow did what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

The global dispatch queue is a shared resource. `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW` tasks run after every other task in the queue at a higher priority has run. If the queue is getting a lot of blocks submitted with a higher priority, your `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW` task may not run for a very long time!

This is documented in the [Concurreny Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW5) as well as the libdispatch [man pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_get_global_queue.3.html)

So, basically, other higher priority tasks are keeping things busy and your low priority task is not getting an opportunity to go.

Comment: The global queues are a shared resource. Something else in your application, or in the system, which may have changed in iOS 7, may be trying to schedule tasks in there that have a higher priority. For example, if you have a UIWebView, that may be scheduling tasks at a higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

I highlighted iMartin's answer "AGIPCGridItem is subclass of UIView. Don't work with UIKit objects on background thread."  He's got it.

I had a very similar issue when moving iOS6 to 7.  I was dispatching an ALAssets request in a background thread.  Once the fetch completed, I would construct the UIImageView, a UILabel, and a wrapper and then send this object to the main/foreground thread to be rendered.  This worked fine on iOS6, but on 7 it was not draw for about 20 seconds.  It would sometime draw after a UI event like a touch.

Fix was to fetch the ALAsset in the background, send that to the main thread where I created the image view, etc. Works like a charm now.