# iOS - Downloading images asynchronously and using them alongside Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

In my Core Data model I have an entity which keeps URLs of images. I want to download these images so I can use them in my `UICollectionView` model, which is an array of my Core Data entities. I want to always be able to access these images synchronously (assuming they have already been downloaded async) so there's no delay between them loading in their respective cell.

Currently, I am using an async method in the `cellForIndexPath:` data source delegate method of the `UICollectionView` but when the collection view is reloaded, if there are images still being downloaded, they get assigned to the wrong cell as cells have been inserted during this time.

This problem seems like it should be very obvious to solve but I cannot work it out.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this out. It is a UITableView but I think it still applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852033/gcd-uitableview-asynchronous-load-images-wrong-cells-are-loaded-until-new-image?lq=1 They suggest you use the NSIndexPath instead of capturing the cell in the asynchronous block.

Comment: Here suggest a different solution based on UIView's tag property: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15668366/1152596

Answer (score 1):

You can download the images asynchronously in `viewDidLoad`, and add them to an NSMUtableArray as follows

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        for (int i = 0; i < carPhotos.count; i++) {

            NSURL *photoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:carPhotos[i]];
            NSData *photoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:photoURL];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData];
            [carImages addObject:image];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });

        }

    });
```

And then check in the `cellForRowAtIndexpath` to ensure that the indexPath matches the arrayIndex, and if you want load a dummy image for not-loaded images, as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CarsAppCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.carMakeLabel.text = carMakes[indexPath.row];
    cell.carModelLabel.text = carModels[indexPath.row];

```
if (carImages.count > indexPath.row) {
    cell.carImage.image = carImages[indexPath.row];
} else {
    cell.carImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dummy.png"];
}

return cell;
```

}

I hope it helps....

Comment: This was what I originally thought about doing, but my UICollectionView uses data from the core data as well as the loaded image, so there's a danger of the two datas being out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you can do:

1. In the cell's prepareForReuse you can cancel any (still) pending image request.
2. In the completion process for the image request you can verify that the image url is still as expected before setting the image.

Something like:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    _imageUrl = nil;
}

-(void)useImageUrl:(NSString*)imageUrl 
{
    _imageUrl = imageUrl;
    if(_imageUrl)
    {
        __weak typeof(self) weak = self;

        [UIImage fetchRemoteImage:imageUrl completion:^(UIImage* image){
            if(weak.imageUrl && [weak.imageUrl isEqualToString:imageUrl] && image) {
                weak.imageView.image = image;
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but how does the first method cancel the request? The second method is a nice idea though :)

Comment: This implementation doesn't implement #1, so you're not confused.

Comment: It just uses prepareForReuse to add a little protection against the image begin set wrong.

Comment: Ah ok, exactly why is weak needed? I remember using it before but forget why.

Comment: In this case it's not strictly "needed" since there is no retain cycle (the cell isn't retaining a reference to the block somehow)  However, it will allow the cell to be safely released before the network operation completes.

Comment: Is there possibly a way to use NSURLSession or similar to cancel the download request?

Comment: Yeah, that depends on how you're actually doing the operation though.  Most of the network toolkits have some mechanism for cancellation.  You probably want to think about whether or not it's really a good idea though.  How likely are they to go back to a cell they've scrolled off screen?  How likely are the images to be shared between multiple cells?  etc.

Comment: It appears that my issue has been solved through reassessing how and when my code gets new data (i.e. to insert new cells) as well as setting the image view's image to nil in `prepareForReuse`

Comment: I can't imagine that this is an absolute fix but if any problems happen again I will have to post all of my code